# Use jQuery to create invoice line calculating vat and total

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling with jQuery (*I am new to it*)
I want to create an invoice page.

Page will have the following row of Text fields:

**Quantity**, **Description**, **Net. Price**, **VAT price**, **Total Price**.

When user starts filling in the **Quantity**, **Description** and when starts typing in **Net. Price** jQuery needs to add another row of empty text fields below.

--If user skips and fills in the **VAT price** without filling in the **Net. price** first jQuery needs to add another row below the existing one.

-- and If user skips **Net price** and **VAT price** and start filling **Total price** jQuery needs to add another row below the existing one.

Then comes the calculation:

when user fills in the **Net. Price** jQuery should automatically fill in the **VAT price** and also **Total Price** (*which is Quantity + VAT Price*)

When user fills in the **VAT Price** (skipping **Net. Price**) jQuery should automatically fill in the **Net. Price** and also **Total Price** (*which is Quantity + VAT Price*)

When user fills in the **Total price** (*skipping Net. and VAT Price*) jQuery should deduct it with **Quantity** and fill in the **Net. Price** and **VAT price**.

do you guys think you could help me?

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id='Invoice' class="row">
    <div class='InvoiceLine row'>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Quantity" id="Quantity"></div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description"></div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="NetPrice" id="NetPrice"></div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="VATPrice" id="VATPrice"></div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="TotalPrice" id="TotalPrice"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I was working on this jQuery code to automatically add row of empty text fields

I managed to get it working. Just missing a small part.

I know I am killing the code but I will make it nicer, with functions and staff.

```
$('#Invoice').on("keyup", ".ItemFields", function() {

var LineNumber = parseInt( $(this).closest('#Invoice').children().last().attr('id') ) + 1

var InvoiceLine = '<div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Quantity_'+LineNumber+'" id="Quantity"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description_'+LineNumber+'"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="NetPrice_'+LineNumber+'" id="NetPrice"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="VATPrice_'+LineNumber+'" id="VATPrice"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="TotalPrice_'+LineNumber+'" id="TotalPrice"></div>';

if ( ($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val() != "" || $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val() != "" ) && $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').attr('id') == $(this).closest('#Invoice').children().last().attr('id') ) {
    $('#Invoice .InvoiceLine').last().after('<div id="'+LineNumber+'" class="InvoiceLine row">'+InvoiceLine+'</div>')
    };
$(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val( ( 0.21 * parseInt($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val()) ) +  parseInt($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val()) );
$(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#TotalPrice').val( parseInt($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#Quantity').val()) * parseInt($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()));
```

});

Comment: No. SO is not a code writing service. If you have a specific question, then yes - the SO community will be able to help you

Comment: Dear Amit, I understand this is a big thing to ask. I am having a trouble with jQuery selectors this is why I have typed my all story on what I want to accomplish. as you can see I have posted the jQuery that adds the lines but I am having a trouble selecting the appropriate Net price to do the calculation.

Comment: I'd start with changing your 'keyup' function to an on 'change' function.  This means the event will fire when the value is changed and you exit the control.  Otherwise, as you have it, the event will fire after every single keystroke (within the targeted DOM elements).

Comment: thanks I will try 'change' function now

Comment: With regard to your difficulty with jQuery selectors, keep in mind that '#Invoice .InvoiceLine' means it will find the id='Invoice' element and then search within it to find something with a class='InvoiceLine' (though actually jQuery reads selectors from right to left but that is a different discussion...).  On the other hand, '.ItemFields #NetPrice' is somewhat silly as the id='NetPrice' should be unique so it does not need to be qualified as within a class=ItemFields.

Comment: Dear nurdyguy. I have 'InvoiceLine' and within that I have 'NetPrice'. I was thinking at every line I could use '(this)' then go to parent then to child to select my 'NetPrice' and 'TotalPrice' this is whay I didn't go for unique IDs. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: could you help me with this. If I am typing in 'VATPrice' how can I go up then come down to select 'NetPrice'?

Comment: ok I got most of the parts working. tomorrow will work on VAT price and Total.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it working as I needed. Thanks to everyone.

here is the code. I know it still needs work to make functions and staff. :) i will do that later.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#Invoice').on("change", ".ItemFields", function() {

    var LineNumber = parseInt( $(this).closest('#Invoice').children().last().attr('id') ) + 1;

    var InvoiceLine = '<div class="ItemFields col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Quantity_'+LineNumber+'" id="Quantity"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description_'+LineNumber+'"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="NetPrice_'+LineNumber+'" id="NetPrice"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="VATPrice_'+LineNumber+'" id="VATPrice"></div><div class="ItemFields col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="TotalPrice_'+LineNumber+'" id="TotalPrice"></div>';

    if (event.target.id == "Quantity" || event.target.id == "NetPrice" || event.target.id == "VATPrice" || event.target.id == "TotalPrice"){

        if ($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#Quantity').val() != "" && ($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val() != "" || $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val() != "" || $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#TotalPrice').val() != "" ) ) {

            switch (event.target.id) {
                case "NetPrice":
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val( parseFloat( ( 0.21 * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val()) ) +  parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val()) ).toFixed(2) );
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#TotalPrice').val( parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#Quantity').val()) * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) ).toFixed(2) );
                    break;
                case "VATPrice":
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val( parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) - ( (0.21 / 1.21) * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) ) ).toFixed(2) );
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#TotalPrice').val( parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#Quantity').val()) * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) ).toFixed(2) );
                    break;
                case "TotalPrice":
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val( parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#TotalPrice').val()) / parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#Quantity').val()) ).toFixed(2) );
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val( parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) - ( (0.21 / 1.21) * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) ) ).toFixed(2) );
                    break;
                case "Quantity":
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val( parseFloat( ( 0.21 * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val()) ) +  parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val()) ).toFixed(2) );
                    $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#TotalPrice').val( parseFloat( parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#Quantity').val()) * parseFloat($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val()) ).toFixed(2) );
                    break;
                };

            };

        };


    if ( ($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#NetPrice').val() != "" || $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').find('#VATPrice').val() != "" ) && $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine').attr('id') == $(this).closest('#Invoice').children().last().attr('id') ) {
        $('#Invoice .InvoiceLine').last().after('<div id="'+LineNumber+'" class="InvoiceLine row">'+InvoiceLine+'</div>')
        };
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think your solution as posted can be improved.  First off you have duplicate ID's in that string if it is appended more than once - which violates the unique id in a document.

Your code seems overly complex and mixes append with calculation.  I would propose adding button(s) to add new rows and (IF you need it) delete buttons on specific rows after the first one.

Here is an example of what I mean:

Markup:

```
<div id='Invoice' class="row" data-lastrowadded="0">
    <div class='InvoiceLine row'>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Quantity" id="Quantity" />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" id="Description" />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NetPrice" id="NetPrice" />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="VATPrice" id="VATPrice" />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemFields col-md-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TotalPrice" id="TotalPrice" /> <span>
        <button class="adder" type="button">+</button>
        <button class="deleter" type="button">X</button></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actionbuttons">
    <button class="adder" type="button">Add New Row</button>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$('.adder').on('click', function () {
    var LineNumber = $('#Invoice').data('lastrowadded') + 1;
    var firstInvoiceLine = $('#Invoice').find('.InvoiceLine.row').first();
    var newInvoiceLine = firstInvoiceLine.clone(true);
    newInvoiceLine.find('.InvoiceLine.row').data('linenumber', LineNumber);
    // fix up the id and name
    newInvoiceLine.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        var previd = $(this).attr('id');
        var prevname = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).attr('id', previd + LineNumber)
            .attr('name', prevname + LineNumber); // keep this sequence
    });
    newInvoiceLine.find('.deleter').show().text("X " + LineNumber);
    $('#Invoice').append(newInvoiceLine);
    $('#Invoice').data('lastrowadded', LineNumber); //update the base number
});
$('.deleter').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('.InvoiceLine.row').remove();
});
$('.deleter').first().hide();
$('#Invoice').on("keyup", ".ItemFields", function () {
    // var LineNumber = parseInt($(this).closest('.InvoiceLine.row').data('linenumber');
    var activeLine = $(this).closest('.InvoiceLine');

    activeLine.find('input[id^="VATPrice"]').val((0.21 * parseInt(activeLine.find('input[id^="NetPrice"]').val(), 10)) + parseInt(activeLine.find('input[id^="NetPrice"]').val(), 10));
    activeLine.find('input[id^="TotalPrice"]').val(parseInt(activeLine.find('input[id^="Quantity"]').val(), 10) * parseInt(activeLine.find('input[id^="VATPrice"]').val(), 10));

});
```

For a final solution here, I would also consider using classes and not ID's which would simplify this code even further.  Note it is complex somewhat to deal with modification to the ids prior to appending it.  It also keeps track of the current line number maximum in a data on the parent.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/1w4bbonu/2/